# Trying to setup redis as session store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, redis

I've been looking at different Gems for redis as session store but they seem to be throwing same/similar error that I can't get around.

For example `gem 'redis-store'` I add it to my gemfile. Here is the content of my `session_store.rb` initializer :

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store Rack::Session::Redis
```

Here is the error I get while doing rails s :

```
/development/config/initializers/session_store.rb:5:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Rack::Session::Redis (NameError)
```

Then I tried another gem [redis-session-store](https://github.com/nickyp/redis-session-store). Here is the content of my initializer when using that gem :

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :redis_session_store,
                                          :db => 0,
                                          :expire_after => 10.minutes,
                                          :key_prefix => "my_app:session:"
```

This is the error I get when starting my server :

```
 /home/workstation/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/redis-session-store-0.2.1/lib/redis-session-store.rb:16:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActionController::Session (NameError)
```

I've never configured this before, can anyone point out what am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you should be using the [`redis-rails`](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails) gem provided by the same user (redis-store that it). Looks like the one you're currently using is for `rack-based` applications.